# How can I expiring External TestFlight users early?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Is there a way I can force old beta versions of my app to expire now, instead of in a month from now?

I have several External testers of my app's Beta through TestFlight that still have old versions of it installed, but those versions haven't expired yet.

The challenge I have is I keep getting bug reports for items that were fixed 3 version ago. The testers either ignored or forgot about the notifications from TestFlight to update.

Of course, I could reply by e-mail to update every time they come back with a bug that has already been fixed, but then I still have to evaluate each bug report that comes in.

Comment: Did you try this: Select "Not available for testing" and Save.

Comment: Yes, you get a message that people with existing installs will not be affected.